# jquery datepicker sending date not as a string using .serialize()

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, format

When I am sending my date using .serialize() it is sending as an string not exact date format ...is there a way I can send it as 09/01/2010... not as a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is posted to the server as a string...this is just how HTTP POST works.  You can change the format, but it'll be a string no matter what date format you use.

If you're using the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) you can populate *another* field used for posting use the [`altField`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altField) and [`altFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat) options, for example:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  altField: '#FieldToPost',
  altFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' //whatever format here
});
```

For format information, [check our your options here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker just writes values to a input box, which is a string.  In the page this form is being posted to, you can convert the string to a date.